# Find relation $R$ on $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ s.t. $R$, $R^2$, $R^3$, and $R^4$ are distinct, but $R=R^5$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

I've made some attempts, but inevitably, I have to add ordered pairs in order to make $R$, $R^2$, $R^3$, and $R^4$ distinct. But how would I get back to $R$ doing $R \circ R^4$? I have no idea how a composition would remove ordered pairs. I was thinking that (maybe) starting with some combination of properties (irreflexive, asymmetric, etc) would lead to the result, but now I believe I should be looking for something completely different and I have no idea where to start. What am I missing?

Comment: I would start with fewer generations.  Can you find one where $R \neq R^2,$ but $R = R^3$.  It seems like you need some chains that lead nowhere so they disappear when you form $R^3$

Comment: Try restricting yourself to a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R = { (1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (4,5), (5,1) }

Comment: Don't you mean $(1, 2)$ for the first one of these?

Comment: I tried this example. In $R^4$ we basically get $\{1,2,3,4,5\} \times \{1,2,3,4,5\}$. How applying $R$ again generates $R$? Isn't $R^4=R^n$ if $n \geq 4$?

Comment: My God, I could delete my previous comment but I'll leave it in case someone else makes the confusion I did. It seems I misunderstood the definition of composition. I was just adding the new ordered pairs on top of the old ones, while these should not be considered. Apologies for the silly mistake!

Comment: @PrimeMover.  Yes.  Correction made.